# Was the HBC (Hudson's Bay Company) mug a deliberate prop in "The Princess Bride"?

Tags: props, the-princess-bride

In "The Princess Bride", Peter Falk is seen holding an HBC mug with the distinctive green/red/yellow/indigo stripes of the Hudson's Bay Company:
[image]

Was this prop a deliberate insertion, or did this "only in Canada" item simply appear by chance?

Comment: All I can find on this topic is two sources which say the same thing as you do, that this is an HBC mug, but don't say why... http://anybody-want-a-peanut.blogspot.com/2011/06/peter-falk-and-hbc-mug.html
https://pl.pinterest.com/pin/340444053059867102/?lp=true

Comment: Its rare thats props in movies are there by pure chance alone. Especially ones with company names. I expect this to be something for eagle eye viewers to notice

Comment: What would be the significance if it were deliberate?

Comment: @OrangeDog, I don't know what the significance would be; but as morbo points out, it would be rare for it not to be deliberate.  That's why I asked.

Comment: @RayButterworth an insignificant production detail would be trivia, which is off-topic

Comment: @OrangeDog, but until it gets an answer, we can't know that it *is* insignificant.  (Catch 22 in reverse?)

Comment: @RayButterworth that doesn't make it on topic. We cannot have a separate question for every single prop in every single production asking if the choice was deliberate.

Comment: @OrangeDog, yes, that was a joke.  Is there a way to rephrase the question  to save it?  Or should I delete it (except that it already has upvotes)?

Comment: i  genuinely interested for an answer. However I can only imagine the answer is a easter egg for history nerds at the most, or a jab at  HBC for some reason (hbc is a very old company that still exists) at worst and unlikely more than that.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093779/trivia?item=tr3587016

Comment: of all we know they forgot to put in a mug or decided last minute that the grandfather should be drinking from a mug, so someone ran to their trailer and said "here use this".

Answer (score 1):

The only thing resembling any sort of a connection is this:

There is a book ["The Princess Story"](https://www.abebooks.com/9780888360021/Princess-story-century-half-West-0888360029/plp) which has one of the HBC's ships in it, which has a similar title to "The Princess Bride". No other relations between the movie and the HBC company can be found online, so it is safe to assume, that this is either meaningless and accidental or some inside joke between director/producer/Peter Falk or someone else. In either of these cases, there is no way any sources confirming such case can be found.

Comment: Apart from having a similar title, is there any actual connection between this book and The Princess Bride?  (either the movie or the original book.)  If not, this "connection" doesn't seem like much of a connection at all, and thus the answer only serve to confuse matters.  (If yes, however, I would welcome being shown that I'm mistaken.)

Comment: @Steve-O that is why I wrote, "resembling any sort of a connection" to prove that there is no real connection, not to confuse